# How to solve an error 404 with Nginx after login on dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, nginx, 404, dashboard

- Magento 1.9.2.1
- Nginx 1.8.1

I'm trying to set up a Magento shop, a development server with Nginx for further change.

Currently, it runs on a server with Apache.

Developing I have no problems with redirects. The frontend works well.
I used to access the dashboard http: //www.domain.tld/index.php/admin/

But it does not work on my Nginx installation.

If you use **http://www.domain.tld/admin/** it asks for my user and password, but then I redirected to a page **http://www.domain.tld//index.php/admin/admin/dashboard/index/** giving a 404 error.

```
server {
    listen      x.xxx.xxx.x:80;
    server_name domain.es www.domain.es;
    root        /home/user/web/domain.es/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.es.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.es.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.es.error.log error;

    location / {

        # START Tamaniut
        try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
        # END tamainut

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/user/web/domain.es/document_errors/;
    }

    #START tamainut
    #location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    #    deny    all;
    #    return  404;
    #}

    ##
    # dont log robots.txt requests
    ##
    location /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }
    location /var/export/            { deny all; }

    # deny htaccess files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    #This @handler it's on several tips on stackExchange, Magento Exchange, but when try restart get: "named location "@handler" can be on the server level only"
    #location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
    #    rewrite / /index.php;
    #}

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    # END Tamainut
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    #include     /home/user/conf/web/nginx.naturjoya.es.conf*;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@handler` is missing in your config. Try the following config. Update root and fastcgi_pass according to your environment.

```
server {   
    listen      x.xxx.xxx.x:80;
    server_name domain.es www.domain.es;

    root /home/user/web/domain.es/public_html;
    index index.php;
    location = /js/index.php/x.js {
        rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    ## Main Magento @location
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    ## These locations are protected
    location ~ /(app|var|downloader|includes|pkginfo)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    ## Images
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        add_header ETag "";
    }

    ## Fonts
    location ~* \.(swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        add_header ETag "";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    ## Execute PHP scripts
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `php{}` block rule to more simple and clear for your self:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Comment: More simple but not work.